# Run function only after another function is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trauling the web to find an answer to this, but everything I find seems to fail.

In a function I want to disable a href link. Once this function is complete (including animations) I want to re-enable the link.

I currently have the following:

```
function prev() {
    $prevId = $('.active').prev('.slide-item').attr('id');
    if ($prevId) {
        $('#prev').bind('click', false);            
        var id = '#'+$prevId;
        $('#thumb-list li a.current').removeClass('current');
        var thumb = '#thumb-list li a'+id;
        $(thumb).addClass('current');
        $('.active').transition({ left: offCanvas }, 300, function() { $(this).hide(); }).removeClass('active');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(id).addClass('active').css({ left: -pageWidth }).show().transition({ left: 0 }, 300).css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0px,0px,0px)"):
        }, 30); 
        prevFinished();
    } else {
        $('.active').css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0px,0px,0px)");
        id = '#'+$('.active').attr('id');
    }
    $prevId = $(id).prev('.slide-item').attr('id');
    $nextId = $(id).next('.slide-item').attr('id');
    prevNextCheck();
}

function prevFinished() {
    $('#prev').unbind('click', false);
}
```

But it doesn't work at all.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

P.S I tried using callbacks, but unless I am doing something terribly wrong it failed every time.

Comment: What is `.transition()`?

Comment: .transition is .animate but a plugin to use CSS3 animations instead.

Comment: Is it this plugin : http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the previous answer you could use jQuery's Deferred and Promises. Depending on when exactly you'd want your functions to be executed it'd look something like this:

```
var deferred = new $.Deferred();
var promise = deferred.promise();

$('.someClass').transition({ left: 0 }, 300, function(e) {
    // .. maybe do some other stuff or maybe not
    deferred.resolve();
});

promise.then(someFunction);

function someFunction() {
    // this runs after your transition has finished
}
```

You can of course chain multiple then together if you wanted.

Additionally if you have multiple functions that you need to wait for to finish you could also use $.when and wait for all of them to finish.

```
$.when(promise1,promise2).then(someFunction);
```

Comment: You can just call promise() on the element and it will return an animation promise by default (the fx queue)

Answer (score -1):

There are a few methods of accomplishing this.

Solution one is to use callbacks. Your animation sequences look overly complex, but it appears you are making a rotation animation for multiple objects, and I don't know the requirements of it. But, one thing I can say is that your callbacks are only encapsulating a small amount of functionality from the looks of it. Widen it out to include EVERY action that is expected to occur after the animation.

Solution two is to use deferred objects and [promises](http://api.jquery.com/?s=promise). [I'm not the best person to ask](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wrangle-async-tasks-with-jquery-promises--net-24135) for a working example of how this works, but the functionality fits your requirement.

Both of these routes are documents jquery features that just need to be put in place correctly.

Comment: Writing an answer without the answer just for saving a spot isnt a good practice here in SO.

Comment: I know, and I don't often do this. I'm juggling a few things right now. I'm almost done

Comment: And for the record, even though the first answer wasn't very defined, it was a reasonable answer. I didn't realize that providing the concept and then later expanding on the thought was considered "writing an answer without the answer". I provided the answer  I intended to provide, but not the details or alternatives

Comment: The -1 was mine, and it was for your final answer, not your placeholder.  This answer effectively says "You can do the thing that you explicitly said didn't work for you (callbacks) or you can use something that I don't know anything about (promises).  Just do it right and it will work."

Comment: I don't wanna start any argument at all, but your first answer was just a tool enumeration. If i'm asking how to make some origami, I do wish to a linear direction, not someone saying to use paper :) Anyway, I was just stating that because you could have undeserved downvote on your final answer just because you used a placeholder!

Comment: And I have no intentions of an argument. My intention was to debate the statement. I understand your statement now with clarification, and I appreciate the direction. I will remember it in future answers. 

@RichieHindle I respect the perspective you have provided. Knowing I do not have adequate knowledge on the subject, I will not attempt to provide a code example of it's implementation. Looking at this now, I understand I could have provided both pieces of information as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @BrettWeber: You're a gentleman.  IMHO a comment would have been more appropriate.

Comment: @BrettWeber That's how every internet conversation should be. We need more people like you.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thank you. I have every intention of continuing the practice as a member of this community.